# How can I increase the content transparecy with CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, background

I want my content be more transparent, I've added the following CSS code:

```
.hentry {
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
```

}

How can I increased that value?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rgba() color codes:
the first 3 values are for rgb
the 4th value is for the alpha channel and defines the opacity of the color
The alpha value can go from zero 0 (transparent) to one 1 (opaque).

Comment: Can you write an example code? I'm just a graphic designer and I'm trying to learn something about programming languages ^^' anyway thanks a lot for the help

Comment: .hentry {
background-color: rgba(50, 115, 220, 0.3);
}
no problem just like that. use the rgb color code

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content to be transparent, you can do this with the help of **opacity** CSS

```
.hentry {
 opacity: 0.8;
}
```

**0.8** is the value, you can define anything between 0 to 0.9 in that depending upon your requirement

Comment: I forgot to specify that there's some texts and images, so adding that code make them transparent too. How can I exclude them?
Thanks a lot for the reply and help